# Laravel Mail::failures() method is not working

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-6

The `failures()` method is not working. It returns an empty array while sending an invalid email.

```php
Mail::send('mail_templates', $messageData, 
    function ($message) use ($firstname, $email_id) {
        $message->to($email_id, $firstname)
            ->subject('Welcome Mail');
});

$a = Mail::failures();

return $a;
```

I checked the from email address.

> Address not found

The notification occurred in `FROM EMAIL` and the mail failure response shows an empty array (`[]`). I want to know if the email is sent or not while the API calls to mail send process in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of this Question 
[How the laravel Mail::failures() function works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045181/how-the-laravel-mailfailures-function-works).

Better refer above Stackoverflow link
In that link there is an answer related to this..
specially read alexrussell comment.

> It's worth nothing that only very specific types of failures are
>   retuned from Swiftmailer: pretty much only failures in the sense that
>   the method used for mail rejected the address/email. With SMTP this is
>   generally okay, as SMTP servers will immediately return a failure, but
>   something like using sendmail will rarely (if ever) return a failure,
>   as the emails are just accepted regardless, and then sent later. As
>   such, if you use sendmail (or maybe even mail) in your mail config,
>   you'll probably need to use a different way to monitor delivery
>   failures. –

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate, you probably shouldn't have answered it, but just vote to close, or link the possible duplicate in the comments.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari : i have provided the link and answer from the link . i told him refer the link and read the solution. but what you said is makes sense in a way ..