# Laravel 8.0 doesnt send email and doesnt return any error

Tags: php, laravel

I have all configurations done correctly, i don't know if i'm missing something, when using mailtrap.io every e-mail is sent correctly but in production simply nothing is sent but doesnt return any erro too.

Here is my `.env` config, every config according to my host

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com.br
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=interno@mydomain.com.br
MAIL_PASSWORD=password1234
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=interno@mydomain.com.br
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My Domain Name"
```

My mail file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class BackupMade extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $url;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->url = route('backups.download');
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Subject')
            ->markdown('emails.backup', [
                'url' => $this->url
            ]);
    }
}
```

I'm using a `artisan command` to send so my artisan command file is that:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Mail\BackupMade;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendBackupEmail extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'backup:send-email';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send a backup e-mail notification.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $address = 'my-email@hotmail.com';

        Mail::to($address)->send(new BackupMade());
        $this->info("Email sent to $address");
    }
}
```

Here is my `config/mail.php`

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

I already ran `php artisan optimize` and `php artisan config:cache` in production but the e-mail is never sent, what can possibly is going wrong?

Comment: If you are using cPanel smtp, then its normal

Comment: Change MAIL_PASSWORD=password1234 with MAIL_PASSWORD="password1234" and clear cache, this might help you.

Comment: @Espresso its normal i cant send emails? What?

Comment: @KaleemShoukat it didn't work

Comment: I think you have to troubleshoot. Pls have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045181/how-the-laravel-mailfailures-function-works/67377605#67377605. That includes my answer.